# XSS with a torrent

Tags: xss

Is it possible to XSS using a BitTorrent tracker. I have been hearing that you can use a torrent to perform XSS. Is it possible ? If so whats the general idea ?

Comment: Please include your sources with your question. What exactly have you heard? What efforts did you make before posting this here?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if the tracker is using HTML/javascript to show content then yes - it's possible.

If there isn't any XSS protection in place, someone could include the following:

`myfile.txt<script>alert(1);</script>`

in a file name or some other field that is rendered and it could potentially execute.

Comment: Can torrent clients render javascript?

Comment: @Aatif Some clients use a web renderer such as Microsoft's WebBrowser control. I've come across binary apps which are vulnerable to XSS. Since the code executes in the local security domain it is possible to do stuff like load ActiveX components or VBScript if the local security policy has not been hardened. These can be used to run arbitrary code in the same context as the application process (e.g. create an FSO object, drop data into file, ShellExecute it).

Comment: @Aatif, In addition here is a Chrome plugin that allows you to track torrents: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jstorrent/anhdpjpojoipgpmfanmedjghaligalgb?hl=en

Comment: @Aatif Also, come to think of it, many torrent clients have a web-based interface. Transmission and Hadouken are headless, so a web interface is a common front-end. uTorrent and Deluge also have optional web interfaces. So it is possible for an XSS condition to arise.

Comment: @Polynomial Ah interesting and enlightening, i think i was limiting my imagination to the my cursory recollection of the default uTorrent Interface. Thanks, very helpful :)